# Following Rails tutorial, undefined method 'create' for nil:NilClass, with nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the Rails tutorial and making changes where appropriate, with the intention that my tutorial project will become a full-fledged production app after the completion of the tutorial.

I've run into a snag with the second model portion of the tutorial. Here is how I've written my second model.

In my `policy.rb`:

```
class Policy < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :insured
end
```

In my `insured.rb`:

```
class Insured < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :policy
end
```

In my `routes.rb`:

```
resources :policies do
    resource :insured
end
```

In my `insureds_controller.rb`:

```
def create
    @policy = Policy.find(params[:policy_id])
    # next line is raising the error
    @insured = @policy.insured.create(insured_params)
    redirect_to @insured
end

private
    def insured_params
        params.permit(:name, :address, :phone, :email)
    end
```

I've inspected the `@policy` object with `render plain: @policy.inspect` and can confirm that ActiveRecord is retrieving the policy correctly. When I inspect the attributes of `@policy`, using `render plain: @policy.attribute_names.inspect`, I don't see an `insured` attribute, which I thought Rails was supposed to automatically manage for me. In the tutorial, an `article` `has_many :comments`, and a comment is supposedly easily created and associated with the parent article with this call: `@article.comments.create(comment_params)`. I also noticed that the tutorial uses `params.require(:comment).permit(...)` while I have to use `params.permit(...)`, after inspecting the `params` hash I saw that the `:insured` attributes existed in the top-level of the hash, instead of being tied to an `:insured` key within the hash.

I tried manually saving and assigning the `@insured` object like so:

```
def create
    @policy = Policy.find(params[:policy_id])
    @insured = Insured.new(insured_params)
    if @insured.save
        @policy.insured = @insured
        redirect_to @insured
    end
end
```

Only to run into the following error in my `.../insureds/new.html.erb`:

```
<h1>New Insured</h1>
<h1><%= @policy.policy_number %></h2>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Cancel', policy_path(@policy) %>
```

Which derives from my partial form `.../insureds/_form.html.erb`:

```
# the following line raises the error
<%= form_with model: @insured, local: true do |form| %>
    # html omitted for brevity
<% end %>
```

Error: 'undefined method `insureds_path`'. This is weird because when I inspect the HTML I can see the form action for this view is `/policies/[:id]/insured`.

Sorry for the massive wall of text, I wanted to show you guys that I did try to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Try `@policy.create_insured(...)`.

Comment: Hi @Phlip, I made this change and a new error was raised on this line `redirect_to @insured`, the error is `undefined method for 'insureds_url'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@maguri, that's not all necessary. The stumbling block I was running into was that Rails couldn't automatically determine the correct routes. When I provided my own urls in the `form_with` declarations, everything went smoothly.

Observe the following change in my `_form.html.erb` for the Insured model, which `belongs_to` Policy, which `has_one` Insured.

```
<%= form_with model: @insured, url: policy_insured_path(@policy) local: true do |form| %>
```

In my updated `insureds_controller.rb` file, using @Phlip's suggestion:

```
def create
    @policy = Policy.find(params[:policy_id])
    @insured = @policy.create_insured(insured_params)
    if @policy.insured.save
        redirect_to policy_insured_path(params[:policy_id])
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

This allows me to keep `routes.rb` clean and simple:

```
resources :policies do
    resource: insured
end
```

Thank you for your answer, it helped me discover the problem was with my routes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
resources :policies do
  # change it for:
  collection do
    get 'insured', to: 'policies#show_insured', as: 'show_policy_insured'
    # maybe unnecessary to be here
    # get 'insured/new', to: 'insureds#new', as: 'new_policy_insured'
    # post 'insured/create', to: 'insureds#create', as: 'create_policy_insured'
    # delete 'insured/delete', to: 'insureds#delete', as: 'delete_policy_insured'
  end
end
# add resources here
resources :insureds
```

In `policy_controller.rb`:

```
def show_insured # 'policy/:id/insureds/
end
```

In `insureds_controller.rb`:

```
def show # '/insureds/:id'
end

def create
  ...
  redirect_to show_policy_insured && return if @insured_policy
end

# before_filter or before_action
@policy = Policy.find(params[:id])
@insured_policy = @policy.insured
```

Check it and *run* this to see your **routes**:

```
$ bundle exec rake routes 


get /policies/:id/insured   => 'policies_controller#show_insured'
get /insureds/:id           => 'insureds_controller#show'
get /insured/new            => 'insureds_controller#new'
post /insureds/create       => 'insureds_controller#create'
delete /insureds/:id/delete => 'insureds_controller#delete'
```

Comment: Hi @maguri, I'm not sure this is the solution. Doing this creates two new routes and deletes one: `GET` and `POST` are created for `policy_insureds`, and the `POST` route is deleted for `policy_insured`. This is incorrect. Each `policy` should have exactly one `insured`. Consider that when a `:policy` resource has one nested `:insured` resource, the `GET` and `POST` routes both exist for `policy_insured`.